# Can't access container service from host on exposed port with my custom iptables

Tags: iptables, docker

I'm running a debian8 container with tomcat8 installed. In my Dockerfile I have `EXPOSE 8080` and when I run the container I set `-p 8080:8080`. It works and I can access tomcat from the host visiting http://localhost:8080 on the browser.

Now, I need to prevent any inbound/outbound connection from and to the internet (in the container) but keep lan connectivity, that's why I added this rules to iptables in the container:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
```

Note that I'm totally not an iptables guru, but a quick test with ping from inside the container shows that I can't ping any WAN address while I'm still able to ping LAN addresses, exacly as I wanted.
Problem is, with those rules, I can't access tomcat from outside the container (browser running on the host) any more. Why? Note that I can ping the host from the container.

My docker info (unix container on windows host):

```
Server Version: 17.03.0-ce
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 25
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 977c511eda0925a723debdc94d09459af49d082a
runc version: a01dafd48bc1c7cc12bdb01206f9fea7dd6feb70
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.9.12-moby
Operating System: Alpine Linux v3.5
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 1.934 GiB
Name: moby
ID: JZ7S:H2PG:4YQ4:GLTO:DVBO:QILY:QYJ2:KRS5:VKJZ:LIXZ:ZAGQ:WEHY
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 29
 Goroutines: 50
 System Time: 2017-03-29T13:32:41.4233556Z
 EventsListeners: 2
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because your rules INPUT and OUPUT only permit access *from* / *to* the 192.168.0.0/24 network. If you want to access from the WAN you have to specify the host or network that can access your service

For example:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s X.X.X.X -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -d X.X.X.X -j ACCEPT
```

X.X.X.X => The Host in the Internet you want permit access your service in your docker.

Comment: Sorry, the question wasn't clear about that, the browser from which I'm trying to access tomcat (just for testing) is running on the same host hosting the container, it's not a WAN access unless docker magic is doing something to make it looks like it is.